# Crash Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, fatal-error

I am getting this crash in my crashlytics report and this is only happening in iPhone 7(iOS 13.*). I have tried to debug this crash in simulator and real devices also but it is not crashing in any of my devices. I don't know what to do, to find out the real cause behind the crash. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
    0  CoreFoundation                 0x1a691980c __exceptionPreprocess
    1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1a6641fa4 objc_exception_throw
    2  CoreFoundation                 0x1a696f350 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1
    3  CoreFoundation                 0x1a69786b4 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:].cold.5
    4  CoreFoundation                 0x1a680650c -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]
    5  CoreFoundation                 0x1a67f83a0 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:]
    6  Mfilterit                      0x101c11ec8 (Missing)
    7  Mfilterit                      0x101c11378 (Missing)
    8  Mfilterit                      0x101c191b8 (Missing)
    9  Mfilterit                      0x101c08d6c (Missing)
    10 Mfilterit                      0x101c0c1fc (Missing)
    11 Mfilterit                      0x101c0c188 (Missing)
    12 Mfilterit                      0x101c0c27c (Missing)
    13 Mfilterit                      0x101c08b9c (Missing)
    14 Mfilterit                      0x101c08b00 (Missing)
    15 Mfilterit                      0x101c09374 (Missing)
    16 Mfilterit                      0x101c0c1fc (Missing)
    17 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a65e6610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
    18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a65e7184 _dispatch_client_callout
    19 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a6593404 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp
    20 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a6593df8 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp
    21 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a659d314 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
    22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a6636f88 _pthread_wqthread
    23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a6639ad4 start_wqthread
```

Comment: Seems like you have used `Mfilterit` named framework, and crash happened inside this framework. You have called some method of this framework inside GCD queue and maybe send some wrong parameters (maybe nil ...)

Answer (score 0):

This type of crash happens if you initialize an NSDictionary using this syntax:

```
NSDictionary* myDictionary = @{@"SomeKey":@"SomeValue",@"SomeKey":@"SomeValue"};
```

It happens if one of the keys or values is nil. You will have to search the project for this syntax and make sure all keys and values aren't nil if this syntax is used.